# Find end node in directed graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have many subgraphs like this one:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(2,1),(3,1),(1,4)])
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

I want to find all start and endnodes. So I use:

```
startnodes = [x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==1 and G.in_degree(x)==0]
endnode = [x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1][0]
print(startnodes, endnode)
[2, 3] 4
```

But some of the subgraphs look like below, with 2 in degrees for end node. How can I find end node for this?

```
G.add_edges_from([(2,1),(3,1)]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you remove `and G.in_degree(x)==1` from the endnode list comp?

Comment: Isn't `G.out_degree(x)==0 ` sufficient to define and end node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one consideration for each:

- An end-node is one without any "out" edges.
- A start-node is one without any "in" edges.

That's all.  If you need to identify your sub-graphs as well, then simply perform any of the standard closure operations from each start node.  Where those sub-graphs have common nodes, merge the sub-graphs.

Comment: What do you do in case there are multiple nodes without "in" or "out" edges?

Comment: Then you have multiple start and end nodes.  I don't see the difficulty here.  Each of OP's examples have two start nodes.